# i want to get value from user to asp .net

Tags: javascript, java, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i was working on website using asp i need to get int value from user and use it on my page.
the value should be entered in popup window or dialog box then store it in variables in cs page.

```
public class InputBox
    {
        public static DialogResult Show(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
        {
            return Show(title, promptText, ref value, null);
        }

//Fuction

        public static DialogResult Show(string title, string promptText, ref string value,
                                        InputBoxValidation validation)
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            Label label = new Label();
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            Button buttonOk = new Button();
            Button buttonCancel = new Button();

            form.Text = title;
            label.Text = promptText;
            textBox.Text = value;

            buttonOk.Text = "OK";
            buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
            textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
            buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
            buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

            label.AutoSize = true;
            textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

            form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });
            form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
            form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;
            if (validation != null)
            {
                form.FormClosing += delegate(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string errorText = validation(textBox.Text);
                        if (e.Cancel = (errorText != ""))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(form, errorText, "Validation Error",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            textBox.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
            value = textBox.Text;
            return dialogResult;
        }
    }

    public delegate string InputBoxValidation(string errorMessage);


private void button_updations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InputBoxValidation validation = delegate(string val)
        {
            if (val == "")
                return "Value cannot be empty.";
            if (!(new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$")).IsMatch(val))
                return "Email address is not valid.";
            return "";
        };

        string value = "";
        if (InputBox.Show("Enter your email address", "Email address:", ref value, validation) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (value == "thazime7@gmail.com")
            {
                dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                button_delete.Visible = true;
                button1.Visible = true;
                button_show.Visible = true;
                label6.Visible = true;
                label4.Visible = true;
                label5.Visible = true;
                textBox_uemail.Visible = true;
                textBox_uname.Visible = true;
                textBox_upassword.Visible = true;
                textBox_delete.Visible = true;
                button_deleteTable.Visible = true;

                button_updatep.Visible = true;
                textBox_updateall.Visible = true;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are not authenticated");
        }
    }
```

i have tried same as c# windows application i was using dialog box but on asp i was not able to do same

Comment: the backend code must catch the data from the client some way. Usually you have a html form on the webpage where you specify the data to send and a controller on the backend that recieves that data.

Comment: i will be more specified i have grid view with select button, when user press select button i need to show a dialog box ask him to enter value after pressing ok the value should be passed back to cs page to make some calculation